# Please help me to understand this problem

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}};
    System.out.println(m1(array)[0]);
    System.out.println(m1(array)[1]);
}

public static int[] m1(int[][] m) {
    int[] result = new int[2];
    result[0] = m.length;
    result[1] = m[0].length;
    return result;
}
```

I am not able to understand how 'array' is passed in methods. According to code, we are trying to pass the 1st row of array in m1 as an argument while m1 method is having a 2-D array as its parameter.

```
System.out.println (m1 (array)[0]);
```

And in m1 hole array is passed how this program is working?
and how I am able to pass (array)[0] in m1 without any parenthesis

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: "*I am not able to understand how 'array' is passed in methods. According to code, we are trying to pass the 1st row of array in m1 as an argument while m1 method is having a 2-D array as its parameter.*"  - The whole array is passed as parameter to `m1`: `m1(array)`

Comment: @dreamcrash I did neither en- nor discourage any votes. Care to explain your comment directed at me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `m1(array)[0]` doesn't *pass the 1st row of array in m1 as an argument*, that syntax means that it pass the **whole** array, **then** you take the first box of the **result**,

To understand it better, here is an equivalent code:

```
int[][] array = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}};
int[] res = m1(array);
System.out.println(res[0]); // will give the m.length,    which is 2
System.out.println(res[1]); // will give the m[0].length, which is 4
```

---

You need to see it

- **as:** `m1(array)    [0]` (method call, then first box of result), you could write `(m1(array))[0]` if it helps to understand
- **not as:** `m1     (array)[0]`, because the parenthesis belong to the method

Comment: Then why in the code we are passing (array)[0] . If we want to pass hole array in m1 we can simply write it as m1(array) (According to the code which I had mention)

Comment: You have a misconception. `m1(array)[0]` takes the 1st element of the **result** returned by the call to `m1(array)` (and passes it to `System.out::println`).

Comment: Sir, I am able to understand your point. But I am still little bit confused that in main function why we are passing (array)[0] in m1. What (array)[0] represent ??

Comment: @manaviyadav,  `m1(array)` returns an array of length 2 (which in that method is called return). The `[0]` at the end is the first value inside the returned array. Hope that helps.